# What changes can be made to code to get the graph that I wanted using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame **"India_variant_df"** and I'm trying to plot a multiline graph using the ggplot2 package. The graph that comes as output is not something that I imagined. I need help to figure out, where am I going wrong.

This is my df.

```
dput(India_variant_df)
    structure(list(month_year = c("Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", 
    "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", 
    "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", 
    "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", 
    "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Apr-2021", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", 
    "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", 
    "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", 
    "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", 
    "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2020", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", 
    "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", 
    "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", 
    "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", 
    "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Aug-2021", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", 
    "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", 
    "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", 
    "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", 
    "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2020", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", 
    "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", 
    "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", 
    "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", 
    "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Dec-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", 
    "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", 
    "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", 
    "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", 
    "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Feb-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", 
    "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", 
    "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", 
    "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", 
    "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jan-2021", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", 
    "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", 
    "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", 
    "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", 
    "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2020", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", 
    "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", 
    "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", 
    "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", 
    "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jul-2021", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", 
    "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", 
    "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", 
    "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", 
    "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2020", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", 
    "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", 
    "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", 
    "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", 
    "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Jun-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", 
    "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", 
    "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", 
    "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", 
    "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "Mar-2021", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", 
    "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", 
    "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", 
    "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", 
    "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2020", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", 
    "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", 
    "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", 
    "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", 
    "May-2021", "May-2021", "May-2021", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", 
    "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", 
    "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", 
    "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", 
    "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2020", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", 
    "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", 
    "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", 
    "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", 
    "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Nov-2021", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", 
    "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", 
    "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", 
    "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", 
    "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2020", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", 
    "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", 
    "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", 
    "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", 
    "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Oct-2021", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", 
    "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", 
    "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", 
    "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", 
    "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2020", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", 
    "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", 
    "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", 
    "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", 
    "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021", "Sep-2021"), variant = c("Alpha", "B.1.1.277", 
    "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", 
    "B.1.367", "B.1.620", "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", 
    "Iota", "Kappa", "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", 
    "S:677H.Robin1", "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", 
    "B.1.1.519", "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", 
    "B.1.620", "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", 
    "Kappa", "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican", "Alpha", "B.1.1.277", "B.1.1.302", "B.1.1.519", 
    "B.1.160", "B.1.177", "B.1.221", "B.1.258", "B.1.367", "B.1.620", 
    "Beta", "Delta", "Epsilon", "Eta", "Gamma", "Iota", "Kappa", 
    "Lambda", "Mu", "non_who", "Omicron", "others", "S:677H.Robin1", 
    "S:677P.Pelican"), num_seqs_of_variant = c(2035L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 121L, 5248L, 0L, 42L, 3L, 1L, 2741L, 
    0L, 0L, 2003L, 0L, 2003L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1046L, 0L, 1046L, 
    0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 5355L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 107L, 0L, 107L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 31L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 
    0L, 2585L, 0L, 2585L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 617L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 18L, 64L, 18L, 
    0L, 0L, 262L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 156L, 
    0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 237L, 0L, 0L, 2356L, 0L, 2349L, 0L, 0L, 134L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 10L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 84L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    28L, 0L, 0L, 2762L, 0L, 2745L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 593L, 0L, 
    593L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 6409L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 19L, 0L, 0L, 219L, 0L, 219L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1383L, 0L, 1383L, 0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 9L, 7684L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 37L, 0L, 0L, 258L, 0L, 257L, 
    0L, 0L, 1672L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 87L, 380L, 
    1L, 50L, 0L, 0L, 1577L, 0L, 0L, 2461L, 0L, 2461L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1120L, 0L, 1120L, 0L, 0L, 639L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 53L, 16940L, 0L, 14L, 1L, 0L, 765L, 0L, 0L, 1387L, 
    0L, 1387L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    28L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 611L, 0L, 611L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4007L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 210L, 5L, 210L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 736L, 0L, 736L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 4123L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 62L, 0L, 61L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 820L, 
    0L, 820L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    6738L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 73L, 0L, 72L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -480L))
```

This is my code.

```
ggplot(data = India_variant_df, aes(x= month_year, y = num_seqs_of_variant, 
                                    group = "variant", colour = variant))+ 
      geom_point(stat = "identity")+
      geom_line()
```

This is the graph I got from the code.
[image]

This is the graph I kinda wanted.(I created using Excel pivot chart tool)
[image]

Comment: First step: Get rid of the quotes, i.e. use `group = variant`.

Comment: The other issue is that your x-axis values aren't ordered chronologically. Change this and what Stefan mentioned and your graph is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As mentioned, use `group = variant`, not `"variant"`.
2. Your x axis is currently categorical (strings), not something number-like. Worse is that they are sorting lexicographically, so they are completely out of (intuitive) order:

   ```r
   sort(unique(India_variant_df$month_year))
   #  [1] "Apr-2021" "Aug-2020" "Aug-2021" "Dec-2020" "Dec-2021" "Feb-2021"
   #  [7] "Jan-2021" "Jul-2020" "Jul-2021" "Jun-2020" "Jun-2021" "Mar-2021"
   # [13] "May-2020" "May-2021" "Nov-2020" "Nov-2021" "Oct-2020" "Oct-2021"
   # [19] "Sep-2020" "Sep-2021"
   ```

   (And `ggplot` is going to sort them for you.)

   Change this to a proper `Date`-class object with:

   ```r
   India_variant_df$date <- as.Date(paste0("01-", India_variant_df$month_year), format = "%d-%b-%Y")
   head(India_variant_df)
   #   month_year   variant num_seqs_of_variant       date
   # 1   Apr-2021     Alpha                2035 2021-04-01
   # 2   Apr-2021 B.1.1.277                   0 2021-04-01
   # 3   Apr-2021 B.1.1.302                   0 2021-04-01
   # 4   Apr-2021 B.1.1.519                   0 2021-04-01
   # 5   Apr-2021   B.1.160                   0 2021-04-01
   # 6   Apr-2021   B.1.177                   0 2021-04-01
   ```
3. In order to get the date labels you want, we need to use `scale_x_date`. The two arguments I'll use are `date_breaks` to set them at monthly intervals, and `labels`; the latter will take a little elbow-grease to get the depressed year, but I think it works. (I don't know of a way to get it to look exactly as your demo pic.)

   ```r
   ggplot(data = India_variant_df, aes(x= date, y = num_seqs_of_variant, 
                                       group = variant, colour = variant))+ 
     geom_point(stat = "identity") +
     geom_line() +
     scale_x_date(
       date_breaks = "1 month",
       labels = function(z) ifelse(seq_along(z) == 2L | format(z, format="%m") == "01",
                                   format(z, format = "%b\n%Y"),
                                   format(z, "%b"))
     )
   ```

   The `ifelse` has two components worth mentioning in its attempt to add the year below certain months.

   - Below every January; for this, `format(z, format="%m")`, which is locale-safe (as far as spelling of January);
   - Since we don't know for certain that the first month shown is or is not January, I show the year under the first month displayed. This gives us a little context, and protects us in the unlikely event that the data only includes Feb-Dec in one year (for which the year would otherwise never be shown). For this, we use `seq_along(z) == 2L`. It's `2L` because the first `z` passed to this anon-func is `NA`, so we go with the second. There could be other trickery to get this perfect (I don't recall offhand if the first element is *always* `NA`).

[image: ggplot with properly ordered and formatted x-axis]

(The rest of the theming is up to you :-)

Answer (score 1):

I removed the quotes and converted the `%b-%Y`col into a Date col.

```
India_variant_df["month_year"] = as.Date(paste0("01-", India_variant_df[["month_year"]]), format = "%d-%b-%Y")
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -480L))


ggplot(data = India_variant_df, aes(x= month_year, y = num_seqs_of_variant, 
                                    group = variant, colour = variant))+ 
  geom_point(stat = "identity")+
  geom_line()
```

**Output:**

[image]